# Text Recommendation: Random Walks (for physicists)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, stochastic-processes, polymers, soft-matter

I am an incoming graduate student in Theoretical Physics in the Netherlands, and I would like to know if any of you could recommend texts on random walks with applications to physics. My university offers a course on random-walks but I unfortunately do not have the pre-requisites (measure theory) to actually take the course. Hence I am looking for rather basic references and more advanced ones too in order to self-teach myself on random-walks with applications to Physics.

My interests lie in the fields of Statistical Physics, Soft Matter and Polymer Physics.

Comment: The first chapter of the book "Statistical Field Theory" by Itzykson and Drouffe has a good discussion of random walks for theoretical physicists.

Answer (score 0):

Howard Berg's "Random Walks in Biology" (https://press.princeton.edu/titles/112.html) is an excellent, very short, and simple introduction to the topic.

Comment: I confirm, this book is great